# Asp MVC application progressively becomes slower as datatables.net tables are redrawn on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a view in my mvc application that utilizes datatables.net for the tables on the page. I have an ajax call to refresh a piece of the page after a certain time period which works fine. The part that is confusing to me is that it becomes less and less responsive the longer the time has passed and becomes unfunctionable until I reload the page entirely. I've discovered the lag is caused by calling a table redraw on ajax success. I'm not currently using server side processing and am using the DOM as the datasource for the table. Any ideas on what the real issue is and how to solve it would greatly be appreciated.

Partial in Main View that gets updated via ajax call:

```
<div id="issues-management">
    @Html.Partial("_IssuesManagement", Model)
</div>
```

Javascript Functions on Main View:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Issues","Tier2")",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(result)
                {
                    $('#issues-management').html(result);
                    //Redraw tables on page load
                    $('#pending-issues-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                    $('#inprogress-issues-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                    $('#followup-issues-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                }
            })


        }, 5000);

        //Global functions to initialize and draw table on initial page load
        initDataTableNet('#pending-issues-table', 1040, 480); 
        initDataTableNet('#inprogress-issues-table', 1040, 480);
        initDataTableNet('#followup-issues-table', 1040, 480);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this and let me know the result:

```
     var process;
     setInterval(function () {

        process = $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Issues","Tier2")",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result)
            {
                $('#issues-management').html(result);
                //Redraw tables on page load
                $('#pending-issues-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                $('#inprogress-issues-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                $('#followup-issues-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                process = null;
            }
        })


    }, 5000);
```